# Pandas line plot without transposing the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this -

```
    Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec Marks
0   30  31  29  15  30  30  30  50  30  30  30  26  Student1
1   45  45  45  45  41  45  35  45  45  45  37  45  Student2
2   21  11  21  21  21  21  21  21  21  21  17  21  Student3
3   30  30  33  30  30  30  50  30  30  30  22  30  Student4
4   39  34  34  34  34  34  23  34  40  34  34  34  Student5
5   41  41  41  28  41  56  41  41  41  41  41  41  Student6
```

If I transpose the data like below, I am able to plot a line graph

```
    Marks   Student1    Student2    Student3    Student4    Student5    Student6
0   Jan       30          45          21          30          39           41
1   Feb       31          45          11          30          34           41
2   Mar       29          45          21          33          34           41
3   Apr       15          45          21          30          34           28
4   May       30          41          21          30          34           41
5   Jun       30          45          21          30          34           56
6   Jul       30          35          21          50          23           41
7   Aug       50          45          21          30          34           41
8   Sep       30          45          21          30          40           41
9   Oct       30          45          21          30          34           41
10  Nov       30          37          17          22          34           41
11  Dec       26          45          21          30          34           41
```

However, my original data is huge, and transposing it is taking too long. Is there some other way to achieve this?

Please note - this is just a dummy dataframe I created for the sake of simplicity, my original data is quite complex and huge.

Answer (score 2):

If you're data is huge, you're probably not going to be able to see anything on the line plot anyways...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_table(StringIO("""    Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec Marks
0   30  31  29  15  30  30  30  50  30  30  30  26  Student1
1   45  45  45  45  41  45  35  45  45  45  37  45  Student2
2   21  11  21  21  21  21  21  21  21  21  17  21  Student3
3   30  30  33  30  30  30  50  30  30  30  22  30  Student4
4   39  34  34  34  34  34  23  34  40  34  34  34  Student5
5   41  41  41  28  41  56  41  41  41  41  41  41  Student6"""), sep='\s+')


x = df.columns.tolist()[:-1]
y = df.iloc[:, :-1].values
for i, j in enumerate(y):
    plt.plot(x, j, label=df['Marks'].iloc[i])
plt.ylim(bottom=0)
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
```

[image]